# ADF remove line break from rows while importing from sharepoint list

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, line-breaks, sharepoint-list

I am trying to import data from a sharepoint list and storing it into a blob storage account as a csv file.

I am having trouble with the line break and rows. Some of the rows have symbols like '' or ' " '. This is causing line break and the data after that is loaded into a new line.

For example -  **While I did not directly receive the email discussed above, I did have the email read to me \Sort me out\ we can chat on phone**

Output -
Row 1 - While I did not directly receive the email discussed above, I did have the email read to me
Row 2 - Sort me out

Row 3 - we can chat on phone

I have tried to do mapping columns in the pipeline but still having the same issue.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide details about what activity you are using, how have you configured your dataset, what is the output that you are getting and the expected output?

Comment: I am using a copy activity which is connected to the sharepoint list (source) and blob storage account (sink). The dataset configuration is set to default. I am expecting the output in a csv file as it appears in the list but for some rows it is doing a line break an creating a new row after that particular symbol as described above.

Comment: So, you are expecting the above given example to be stored in a single line? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. in one line correct

Comment: What are the row and column delimiters that you want to apply on data that you need to save?

Comment: Column delimiter ( , ) and row delimiter (\n,\r)

Comment: and Quote character (")

Comment: Have you tried configuring the same in your sink delimited text dataset? As in this [reference image](https://i.imgur.com/lfnpEF5.png)

Comment: Yes i have the same configuration